# Confusion between Windows server 2008 Datacenter and Windows server 2012 RTM on Amazon ec2

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012

I am going to deploy a dot net website on amazon ec2 with IIS as webserver. Amazon is offering two windows AMI one is **Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Datacenter edition and 64-bit architecture** and other is **Microsoft Windows Server 2012 RTM with 64-bit architecture**

As Server 2012 is named as RTM, I am not sure how mature it is to handle live server and software compatibility. My website is going to take good traffic. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing your own research, testing, assessment and decision-making.

Server 2012 comes with the latest version of IIS (8.0), whereas Server 2008R2 comes with IIS 7.5.  Server 2012 (and IIS 8) are newer, and have additional features, whereas IIS 7.5 is older, but more mature.  [You'll probably get the most use out of reading up on the feature improvements between IIS 7.5 and 8.0](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8), and deciding whether you'd rather have the improvements in the newer version, or whatever benefit your perceive from the "maturity" of IIS 7.5.

Hell, if you were really on top of things, you'd probably use [iis express](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview) to get a working copy of your website on both platforms and decide which one works better for your needs.

Comment: "If you were really on top of things"?  You crack me up.